# sort and get unique files after removing extension of filename

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to remove filename after the second underscore and get the unique files. I saw many answers and formed a script. This script is working fine till the cut command but it is not able to give the unique filenames.  I have tried the following command but i am not getting desired output.

script used:

```
 for filename in ${path/to/files}/*.gz; 
    do
    fname=$(basename ${filename} | cut -f 1-2 -d "_" | sort | uniq)
echo "${fname}"
    done
```

file example:

1. filename1_00_1.gz
2. filename1_00_2.gz
3. filename2_00_1.gz
4. filename2_00_2.gz

Required output:

1. filename1_00
2. filename2_00

So, with all of that said. how can I get a unique list of files in the required output format?
Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply `uniq` and `sort` are you are done printing the files (it's better to identify uniques first before sorting them):

```
for filename in ${path/to/files}/*.gz;
    do
        fname=$(basename ${filename} | cut -f 1-2 -d "_" );
        echo "${fname}";
    done | uniq | sort
```

Or just do

```
for filename in ${path/to/files}/*.gz; do echo ${filename%_*.gz}; done | uniq | sort
```

Comment: I want to add another command to the loop after sorting files, where should I add it?

Comment: You can add it with `xargs` after `sort` like: `| xargs bowtie2 -x`. You can set the flag for your bowtie command appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

```
for f in *.gz; do echo ${f%_*.gz}; done | sort | uniq
```

Comment: It is always recommended that you add context to your code. It will help future SO members when they stumble on this answer if there is explanation to the code.